# How to refer to members of a function object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, this, member

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
function foo() { alert(this.bar); }
foo.bar = "Hello world";
foo();
```

That doesn't work because I believe `this` refers to the global object (`window`) rather than `foo`. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refer to the object used to call the method. By default, it will be the `window` object.

In your case, you should get the parameter in the function object directly using the named function as it is available in the scope.

```
function foo() { alert(foo.bar); }
foo.bar = "Hello world";
foo();
```

You shouldn't use `this` as doing something like this:

```
foo.call({})
```

`this` will be equal to the empty object.

Comment: This is the best solution (at least for my use case), thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Possibly try using `prototype`:

```js
function foo() {
  alert(this.bar);
}
foo.prototype.bar = "Hello world";
new foo(); //new object
```

Recommended option:

```js
function foo(bar) { //constructor argument
  this.bar = bar;
}
foo.prototype.getBar = function() {
  alert(this.bar);
};
new foo("Hello world").getBar();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd choose to do it this way, as it makes use of the prototype chain.

```
function Foo() { return (this===window) ? new Foo() : this; }
Foo.prototype.hi = function() { alert(this.bar) };
Foo.prototype.bar = "Hi!";

var tmp = new Foo();
tmp.hi();
```